# How to display WooCommerce downloads table using PHP code or Shotcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, download, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to display woocommerce download table on the dashboard endpoint. After studying the woocommerce download endpoint file i notice woocommerce uses the below code to display the download table;

```
$downloads     = WC()->customer->get_downloadable_products();
$has_downloads = (bool) $downloads;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_downloads', $has_downloads ); ?>

<?php if ( $has_downloads ) : ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_available_downloads' ); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_available_downloads', $downloads ); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_available_downloads' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-Message woocommerce-Message--info woocommerce-info">
        <a class="woocommerce-Button button" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>">
            <?php esc_html_e( 'Go shop', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        </a>
        <?php esc_html_e( 'No downloads available yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_account_downloads', $has_downloads ); ?>
```

what I want to achieve is to display the 5 latest downloads in table format. will like to know how to limit this action `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_available_downloads', $downloads ); ?>` to only display the latest 5 downloads.

**UPDATE**

This is the download table in the Woocommerce Download Endpoint Page
[image]

in which I want to display the same exact table structure on the dashboard endpoint page

[image]

Comment: Use [wc_get_customer_available_downloads()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_customer_available_downloads.html#527), it returns an array of downloads the customer has permission to. Once returned just loop through the array and echo only 5 using a counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 2 ways:

**Option 1 - Using a filter hook** *(filtering on a **specific endpoint**)*:

> The filter `woocommerce_customer_get_downloadable_products` is located inside the code from `WC_CUstomer` [`get_downloadable_products()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_customer_available_downloads.html#521-610) method.

The following will give you the 5 latest downloads in a **specific endpoint** *(Here on My Account > `downloads` endpoint)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_get_downloadable_products', 'filter_customer_downloadable_products', 10, 1 );
function filter_customer_downloadable_products( $downloads ) {
    $limit = 5; // Number of downloads to keep

    // Only on My account Downloads section for more than 5 downloads
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'downloads' ) && sizeof($downloads) > $limit ) {
        $keys_by_order_id = $sorted_downloads = array();
        $count = 0;

        // Loop through the downloads array
        foreach( $downloads as $key => $download ) {
            // Store the array key with the order ID
            $keys_by_order_id[$key] = $download['order_id']; 
        }

        // Sorting the array by Order Ids in DESC order
        arsort($keys_by_order_id); 

        // Loop through the sorted array
        foreach( $keys_by_order_id as $key => $order_id ) {
            // Set the corresponding  download in a new array (sorted)
            $sorted_downloads[] = $downloads[$key];
            $count++; // Increase the count
            // When the count reaches the limit
            if( $count === $limit ) {
                break; // We stop the loop
            }
        }
        return $sorted_downloads;
    }
    return $downloads;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Option 2 - Using a custom function that filters:**

Just use this function, to get from customer `$downloads` variable the latest 5 downloads.

It can be used anywhere.

```
function get_customer_latest_downloads( $downloads, $limit = 5 ) {
    // Only on my account pages for more than 5 downloads
    if( sizeof($downloads) > $limit ) {
        $keys_by_order_id = $sorted_downloads = array();
        $count = 0;

        // Loop through the downloads array
        foreach( $downloads as $key => $download ) {
            // Store the array key with the order ID
            $keys_by_order_id[$key] = $download['order_id']; 
        }

        // Sorting the array by Order Ids in DESC order
        arsort($keys_by_order_id); 

        // Loop through the sorted array
        foreach( $keys_by_order_id as $key => $order_id ) {
            // Set the corresponding  download in a new array (sorted)
            $sorted_downloads[] = $downloads[$key];
            $count++; // Increase the count
            // When the count reaches the limit
            if( $count === $limit ) {
                break; // We stop the loop
            }
        }
        return $sorted_downloads;
    }
    return $downloads;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE Example** *(in a template or a shortcode)*:

```
$downloads     = WC()->customer->get_downloadable_products();

$downloads     = get_customer_latest_downloads( $downloads ); // The 5 latest downloads

// Testing the array raw output
echo '<pre>'; print_r($downloads); echo '</pre>';
```

---

**Note:** Action hooks doesn't filter data.

Comment: Without hook version is what i'm diving right into, as i want to place the table in a specific section of my custom woocommerce dashboard area... checking the code

Comment: I have tried the second method which looks like what will work for me as i want to place it in a certain area but after placing the code and using the Usage Example, i'm getting `Notice: Array to string conversion in` ... I then did a test purchase to see if it was because there wasn't any download for me as the user  and after the test purchase, still same error

Comment: Just tried method one ... and still same Notice. Maybe i'm the one not getting the usage of this code.

Comment: Woocommerce Version 3.6.2 ...  I added the second code in your answer into my functions.php file and i went to the dashboard file in MY_THEME > woocommerce> myaccount > and added the USAGE Example you gave and i got the Notice error

Comment: I did the same thing and I get arrays, is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example to illustrate how you would manipulate the downloads list before it is displayed by WooCommerce.

The most effective way would be using a filter. This function simply returns the first five downloads in the array. To ensure that the five downloads it returns are the most recent you will need to do a bit more work.

```
// Define the callback
function filter_woocommerce_customer_available_downloads($downloads, $customer_id) { 

    // Manipulate download data here, this example we'll get the first 5 downloads in the array
    $downloads = array_slice($downloads, 0, 5);

    // Return first five downloads
    return $downloads;

}; 
// Add the filter, this tells wordpress to apply this filter every time available downloads is called
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_available_downloads', 'filter_woocommerce_customer_available_downloads', 10, 2 );
```

Place this at the bottom of your "functions.php" file in your theme. Please keep in mind that this is a quick and dirty example and is untested.

Comment: Thanks so much for the code... after going through the above code, i then realize that this will print out or return the list of 5 downloads available to a particular user. Is there a way to output this result in the default Woocommerce Download Table? (table like the Orders Endpoint table? (i.e. to rely on woocommerce function to retuen the result in table format

Comment: That's not what this filter does. The filter is passed the array of downloadable items - you can manipulate that array which is what the above code does. You'll need to modify the code to step through the array and count how many times it has been downloaded and if over 5 then you can remove that item from the array. The filter needs to return the array at the end - this would then be processed using the normal woocommerce templates.

Answer (score 1):

Following the code by @LoicTheAztec Second option (Option 2), I then added the WooCommerce Download Template into a shortcode while adding the function in @LoicTheAztec Option 2 to filter the output. Code Below;

```
function make_customer_download_output_five_products() {
    $downloads     = WC()->customer->get_downloadable_products();
    $downloads  = get_customer_latest_downloads($downloads); //Here is the function from Option 2
    $has_downloads = (bool) $downloads;
    ob_start();

    if ( $has_downloads ) {
        do_action( 'woocommerce_available_downloads', $downloads );
    } else {
        ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-Message woocommerce-Message--info woocommerce-info">
            <a class="woocommerce-Button button" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>">
                <?php esc_html_e( 'Go shop', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            </a>
            <?php esc_html_e( 'No downloads available yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
     }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('your_downloads', 'make_customer_download_output_five_products');
```

You can then add the shortcode to any page of choice using `do_shortcode(['your_downloads'])`.

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.